# Android C library built on OS X and "ranlib: warning for library..."

Tags: android, c, macos, android-ndk

When I tried to build my c library on OS X 10.7.3, I use android-sdk-mac2.2, sdk tools version is 12, and use android-ndk-r6. When I finished my compiling it said :

```
ranlib: warning for library libsystem.a the table of contents is 
empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

I tried to use this `libsystem.a`, and it said could not read symbols: `Archive has no index , run ran lib to add one`.

Is anyone knowing why? And what should I do to compile successfully ?

Thanks very much .

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if this is your situation, but the Makefile I was using hard-coded ranlib to /usr/bin/ranlib. Apparently the Mac ranlib is not compatible with the Android ranlib.

Comment: Thanks Dave! This was exactly one of my 1000 problems on my way to compiling vlc for android on OS X.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no `ranlib` in the NDK. What did you use to create the indexes?

Comment: @jww there is for me:`./ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi-ranlib`. You might need to install one of the Android SDK (Build-/Platform-)Tools packages via the SDK Manager.